# Tweepy does not let me run api.get_user with a list of users and also not on a single person

Tags: python, media, data-mining, tweepy

```
api = tweepy.API(auth)
userID_list = ["elonmusk", "BarackObama"]

for userxyz in userID_list:

    user_info = api.get_user(userxyz)
    name = user_info.name
    description = user_info.description
    location = user_info.name.location
    followers_count = user_info.followers_count
    friends_count = user_info.friends_count
```

Writes this Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/wilsi/Desktop/test 123.py", line 36, in <module>
    user_info = api.get_user(userxyz)
  File "C:\Users\wilsi\Desktop\venv\lib\site-packages\tweepy\api.py", line 46, in wrapper
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: get_user() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Answer (score 1):

[`API.get_user`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.4.0/api.html#tweepy.API.get_user) only accepts a single user as a `user_id` or `screen_name` keyword argument.

See also [the FAQ section in Tweepy's documentation about this](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.4.0/faq.html#why-am-i-getting-a-typeerror-about-an-api-method-taking-1-positional-argument-but-given-2).

For code block usage, see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help.

Comment: How do i need to adjust the code, so that it works?`

Comment: You can pass `userxyz` as the `screen_name` keyword argument.